# iterator type for primitive type arrays

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++builder, type-traits

`std::copy<InputInterator, OutputIterator>( /*...*/ );`

How to determine `InputInterator` and `OutputIterator` types for an array of doubles `double d[]`? Is there some kind of `iterator_traits<double*>::iterator_type`?

upd: i use very old compiler, so i need explicit instantiation

Comment: I suppose you mean you need explicit _instantiation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need this? `copy` is a function, so, use simply

```
std::copy(d, d + size, d);
```

This call will automatically deduce the types of arguments.

And also, there is `std::iterator_traits<T*>::pointer`, that evaluates for `double*` as `double*` and you can simply use

`std::copy<double*, double*>(d, d + size, d);`

if you want.

Comment: Because i use very old compiler

Comment: @fogbit: Stop using such a beast.

Comment: @sbi: i wouldn't mind you to convince my boss to rewrite the whole old project with new compiller

Comment: @fogbit: Such a compiler has to be older than 10 years. What is that, TC3.1?? The project should have been, not to be rewritten, but ported, to a modern compiler almost a decade ago. Putting this off further only increases the pain.

Comment: @fogbit: At the very least dig out some copy of BCB6 and port to that. But, yeah, if the coded uses BCB's RAD GUI features, it's stuck in a dead end. OTOH, despite all the bugs in BCB4, I am pretty sure that it implemented template argument deduction.

Comment: @sbi: when i write ``std::copy(d, d + size, d);`` it says it doesn't know about types of the ``Input`` and ``Output`` iterators. When i write ``std::copy<const double*, double>(/*...*/)`` everything works fine.

Comment: @fogbit: Yeah, BCB always had glaring template bugs. _Shrug._ (It should be `const double*, double*`, BTW. Note the 2nd `*`.) Migrate away from BCB. And if your boss doesn't want this, migrate away from that boss.

Comment: `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::pointer` designates the return type of `it->` (where `it` has type `Iter`). It is not the appropriate type to pass to `std::copy` (although in this case it happens to work). In `std::iterator_traits<T*>`, the type that designates the iterator is... `T*`, the template parameter of `std::iterator_traits`.